# Yii2 Gii Connection Refused

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am setting up a new **Yii2** project, and have necountered some troubles using Gii model generator.
I have two computers both  with **Ubuntu 16.04**, on pc A i develop, pc B is a virtual server used for hosting db and webserver.

Installation seems to be succesfull, i can see the main page, and i can log in and log out in that project, also i can use all the features of **Gii** excluding **Model generator**, when i try to access this section, i get the following error:

"**Database Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused**"

I am using the same credentials to log to mysql through phpmyadmin and in project. And i can log to the db through phpmyadmin, but gii keeps throwing Database exception.

**What am i doing wrong?**

Comment: Did you change the IP address on the NON Server PC to look at the Server IP instead of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: If you ask, whether i edited the config/web.php file, then yes i did. Credentials there are the same i am using to log into phpmyadmin and to log in directly through shh tunnel.

Comment: Then did you check that the MYSQL account you are using is allowed to login from a remote ip?

Comment: Yes i am, ip for that user is set to my explicit IP and %

Comment: did you try to access the database directly from the browser of the Non Server PC?

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean by accessing db from browser, but i was able to connect to it using phpmyadmin and from console (through SSH tunnel from A to B.) So did not try remote access yet, because both of methods described above connect from localhost. Later today i'll write a mini script that will tell, if php is able to connect to the db remotely.